# Lists.GetListItems Query for items with a specific author

Tags: web-services, caml-query

I am trying to query a list in SharePoint 2007 to get the items of the list that were created by a specified user.  Here is my CAML:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Author" />
            <Value Type="Text">1073741823;#System Account</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

Actually, I've tried it lots of different ways, but no matter what I try, I get `SoapServerException`.  I've tried changing around the `Name` attribute of the `FieldRef` and the `Type` attribute of the `Value`, as well as the inner text of the `Value`.  There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to create a CAML query like this...  What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have the user id you could try something like this:

```
<Where>
<Eq>
<FieldRef Name='fieldname' LookupId='TRUE' />
<Value Type='Lookup'>lookupid
</Value>
</Eq>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Author" />
            <Value Type="Text">System Account</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where> 
</Query>
```

When querying for a particular name, the `Type` attribute of the `Value` must be text and the inner text of the `Value` node must be the user profile `Name`, as returned by the usergroup.asmx service method `GetAllUserCollectionFromWeb`.